# how to rename folder in php

Tags: php

```
        $currectdir= getcwd();
        echo ">path>".$folder="{$currectdir}\\video\\{$std1}";
        if(is_dir($folder))
        {
          echo "is in loop";
          echo ">>".$newpath="{$currectdir}\\video\\{$std}";
          $done=rename($folder,$newpath);
          var_dump($done);
        }
```

> error:
>   Warning: rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\elearingapp\video\5 ,C:\xampp\htdocs\elearingapp\video\6): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123) in C:\xampp\htdocs\elearingapp\std_view.php on line 31
>   bool(false)

Comment: Please, add the output of `var_dump($std1)` and `var_dump($std)`.

Comment: There is so much wrong and missing from the code sample and no explanation at all of what you are trying to achiveve - voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_rename.asp

give the directory name for changing the name